# new relic sqlserver plugin failing to report metrics

Tags: sql-server, newrelic-platform

I am getting the following error message and hence metrics not collecting for SQL Server when using new relic
     I am a little confused as the basic server monitor for this box is working, and it looks like metrics are being collected based on previous messages in the log file.
Any thoughts or solutions are much appreciated, Ive been waiting for days for help from newrelic support, but it hasn't been forthcoming.

```
>2013-08-21 10:25:09,974 [8] ERROR - Error sending data to connector 
>System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out 
>at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) 
>at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() 
>at NewRelic.Platform.Binding.DotNET.Request.Send() 
>at NewRelic.Microsoft.SqlServer.Plugin.Communication.SqlRequest.SendData() 
>at NewRelic.Microsoft.SqlServer.Plugin.MetricCollector.SendComponentDataToCollector(ISqlEndpoint >endpoint) 
>2013-08-21 10:25:09,975 [SqlPoller] INFO - Recorded 186 metrics 
>2013-08-21 10:25:09,975 [SqlPoller] DEBUG - SqlPoller: Sleeping for 00:01:00
```

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 0):

While most New Relic Platform plugins are supported by the plugin author, this particular plugin is supported by New Relic. Please follow up with our support team so we can help you achieve a resolution.

You can reach New Relic support here: http://support.newrelic.com/

Answer (score 0):

Response from new relic around this issue is regarding the use of proxies in our network, and the lack of proxy configuration allowed by the sql server plugin at this stage.

Comment: The latest version of the SQL Server plugin (2.0.0.0) has support for proxies. The setup is detailed in README file.